# Fetching a deleted object from S3 causes access denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some code that requests an object from S3. If it doesn't exist, an exception is thrown that has the message...

```
The specified key does not exist.
```

Once the object has been created, if it's subsequently deleted then when the object is re-requested it doesn't throw the same exception. Instead, it says access denied.

Why is this? Is there a way of deleting an object such that it's not remembered by S3? Versioning on the bucket is disabled.

I'm using a policy assigned to a role assigned to an EC2 instance. If I delete the permission set on the policy and recreate it then the issue is reset.

Also, this issue doesn't happen if I set the policy to all resources and all operations.

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure that you are using the same (or equivalent) credentials? Here's how things work, afaik. If an object does not exist you will get one of two responses: AccessDenied if you do not have permission to list the object, and NoSuchKey if you do have permission to list the object (though it might require head, not list, I'm not 100% sure). The reason for the former is to prevent unauthorized attackers from determining the existence of objects.

Comment: When you create the object in s3 then you will always have it available and it also gets copied across other availability zones, the only reason why the access denied would appear is because:

1. your iam role does not have the right policy attached
2. you are using the wrong credentials or profile

But then if you delete it then you have the eventual consistency, which means that even if you delete the object it might still exist for sometime, that is why s3 has what is called [eventual consistency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html)

Comment: If you simply wait a few minutes and then retry, is AccessDenied replaced by NoSuchKey?

Comment: @jarmod It's still giving AccessDenied after ten minutes.

Comment: The only thing that seems to fix it is creating a new permissions object allowing all actions and all resources.

Comment: You never stated what specific S3 permissions you gave to the role used by the instance profile. As previously mentioned, if they don't include `s3:ListBucket` then requests for non-existing objects will return `access denied` rather then what most people would expect to be a 404 response. If adding admin permissions to the role solved your problem, then you didn't properly setup the S3 permissions

Comment: I've added ListBucket and it hasn't changed the outcome. I've had... GetObject, PutObject and DeleteObject. `access denied` makes an appearance only after a deleted object is subsequently requested, not if it's requested before it's existed..

Comment: When you say that you have some code that "requests an object from S3", can you elaborate? A simple awscli test doesn't exhibit the same symptoms that you're seeing. Can you provide more detail on which SDK and language you are using, plus what SDK methods you are using to request the object.

Comment: @jarmod I'm using .net SDK. I have tried using credentials supplied directly to the AmazonS3Client when creating it in code and this issue doesn't occur. Please could you try testing a role assigned to an EC2 instance? I think that's where the problem is. Also, when doing this, it works fine when all actions and all resources are selected. It's narrowing down the bucket and the actions that's breaking it. Maybe I'm only missing an action.

Comment: @Ngenator Yes, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `ListBucket` action from the policy.

But it's only needed to read an object that's been deleted.

Arguably, that's a bug. At least, it's an inconsistency.